# Using PyQGIS GDAL Driver

Tags: pyqgis, osgeo

I'm Trying to load S-57 chart files into PyQGIS standalone application.
using

```
depare = QgsVectorLayer(r"8V8POA02.000|layername=DEPARE","DEPARE","ogr")
```

which returns

```
ERROR 4: S57 Driver doesn't support update.
```

So went a different path by loading the file using OGR manually

```
Def readchart(file): 
   driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("S57")
   data = driver.Open(file)
   #Large code that extracts each feature
```

This used to work on a different project where it would return ~30 features.
But somehow, by using PyQGIS, it's only returning 5 features of which are none of the features i expected.

It does return, however,
about 30 times

```
ERROR 1: Invalid index : -1
```

So i am confused whether who or what is causing this.
Does somebody know anything related to this?

Answer (score 0):

Alright so it turns out.

I'm using the vscode pqgis-standalone from https://github.com/MarByteBeep/pyqgis-standalone

works great in order to get the paths aligned for vscode

BUT that was also the problem,

i needed to configure

```
GDAL_DATA=${OSGEO4W_ROOT}/apps/gdal/share/gdal
```

correctly inside .env of the workspace.
which did the trick.

so as a reminder,
check your paths ;)